# Haskell, how can I traverse a [[String type]] to check whether a given string is in the list?

Tags: haskell

I am having a problem, I have a list like this `[["A1","A2","A3"],["B1","B2","B3"],["A1","B3""C3"]]`
I want to return a list if every string contains 2,
the desired return should be as follows:

```
[["A1","A2","A3"],["B1","B2","B3"]]
```

my recent approach is

```
isIn :: Int -> [String] -> Bool
isIn a [] = False
isIn a (x:xs)
  | show a == x = True
  | otherwise = isIn a xs
```

And I tested it using the list above it gave me False, what did I wrong?
How should I fix this?

Comment: What does your code do? (I know what it does, but I want you to tell me)

Comment: this code just a filter function and I want to apply it to my other function

Comment: What other function? And what does it *actually do*?

Comment: `filter (any (elem '2'))`

Comment: What do you mean? I just wanna use this function to find every pair of the list that contains 2 or other words I want to search

Comment: I don't know if you meant me or 4castle, but my question is literally *what does your function do?*...

Answer (score 0):

By the type definition `isIn :: Int -> [String] -> Bool` I assume that the function is iterating the list of strings (for example `["A1","A2","A3"]`).

Therefore, the problem is in `show a == x`. `x` is equal to `"A1"`, `"A2"`, `"A3"`; `show 2` is `"2"`; but `"2"` is not equal to any of these strings.

You'll need to use the function that verifies that a string `contains` "2", not `equal` to "2" (there's [elem](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:elem) function)

Or implement it:

```
isInString :: Int -> [Char] -> Bool
isInString a [] = False
isInString a (x:xs)
  | intToDigit a == x = True
  | otherwise = isInString a xs
```

And then use it in `isIn`:

```
isIn :: Int -> [String] -> Bool
isIn a [] = False
isIn a (x:xs)
  | isInString a x = True
  | otherwise = isIn a xs
```